# get the URL parameter followed by #-php

Tags: php, javascript

I have a dynamic page in php.I want to extract all the string follwed by # in the URL.The page is a bit like ajax and it doent loads fully just the URL changes.So i need a mechanism as and when the url changes I can capture the string followed by # and do appropriate actions.

eg:  `index.php#FJDrfjg67`

I need

```
FJDrfjg67
```

Please Help

Comment: Also consult as well the javascript reference of your choice, e.g.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onhashchange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `window.location.hash` to get the # content  and sent it by ajax

or you can also get this by  [**`parse_url()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

```
echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_FRAGMENT );
```

its the `fragment` ( after the hashmark #)

Comment: I mean i just want the contents after the hash.The page is made by other author and it changes automatically.I want to make sure that when the url changes i capture the string followed by hash

Comment: how you are changing the url ?

Comment: I am not changing...It gets changed automatically...I dont understand the program.So i just need to detect a change

Comment: well first  we need to know how it change and then i can tell you suitable solution

Answer (score 0):

It's not sent to the browser. You need to use JavaScript and send it using Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers don't send part of URI after hash `#` to server side. You need to do this extraction in browser itself i.e. in Javascript.

Using Javascript you can do:

```
var hashtag = window.location.hash.replace(/^#/, "");
```

To get the part of URI after #

You can then send the `hashtag` variable to server side using a query parameter or in URI itself by appending to the `location.href` in your javascript.